# Running rpm does nothing

Tags: rpm

I'm not sure what happened with rpm on my system. This is a CentOS 6.3 VM hosted on Amazon EC2 if that makes a difference.

When I run any rpm commands, it returns to the command prompt doing nothing. The only thing that does return anything is:

`rpm --help`

Anything else just does nothing. No error message, no log message, nothing... I don't know how to continue.

By using strace as suggested, I believe that rpm is failing during the reading of /usr/lib/rpm/rpmrc. I have compared this rpmrc with a working system and there are no differences. I'm not sure how to continue...

Here are the last lines from strace:

```
stat("/home/tscdev/.rpmrc", 0x7fffffb4ffc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/lib/rpm/rpmrc", R_OK)      = 0
open("/usr/lib/rpm/rpmrc", O_RDONLY)    = 3
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=13698, ...}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

Here is a directory listing of the database directory (/var/lib/rpm):

```
total 48532
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Apr 19 12:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root     4096 Feb 14 14:44 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2826240 Feb 14 14:44 Basenames
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    12288 Feb 14 14:44 Conflictname
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1478656 Feb 14 14:44 Dirnames
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  5238784 Feb 14 14:44 Filedigests
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    16384 Feb 14 14:44 Group
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    12288 Feb 14 14:44 Installtid
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    24576 Feb 14 14:44 Name
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    12288 Feb 14 14:44 Obsoletename
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 37629952 Feb 14 14:44 Packages
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1335296 Feb 14 14:44 Providename
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   655360 Feb 14 14:44 Provideversion
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    12288 Aug 20  2012 Pubkeys
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   204800 Feb 14 14:44 Requirename
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   139264 Feb 14 14:44 Requireversion
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    45056 Feb 14 14:44 Sha1header
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    40960 Feb 14 14:44 Sigmd5
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    12288 Oct 29 17:12 Triggername
```

Comment: What about: strace rpm ?

Comment: @MarekWajdzik - Thanks for the suggestion. That at least got me something to look at. I have to take a look at the system calls to see what is causing the hangup.

Comment: try rpm -qa to see if the database is happy. You could try rpm --rebuilddb

Comment: @egorgry I've tried both rpm -qa and rpm --rebuilddb. Both commands do nothing and return to the command prompt.

Comment: apt-get install rpm ;)does yum work? Any additional info in the logs?

Comment: No apt-get on this system. yum does not work (which was my original problem.) I narrowed down yum not working to rpm not working... There is no information in the logs that I can see.

Comment: sorry apt-get was a dumb joke. I upvoted the question to try and get it more attention. try locate rpm to see if all the bits are installed.

Comment: @egorgry Thanks for trying to help. I should have noticed your smiley. :)

Comment: Can you do an `ls -al /var/lib/rpm` and post that in your question?  And (I apologise for even asking) confirm that you're running these commands as root?

Comment: OK, thanks, that blows my hypothesis out of the water.

Answer (score 0):

On my system the `rpm --help` output comes from processing files in `/usr/lib/rpm/rpmpopt*`, which themselves come as part of the rpm package. To check this on your server I would run:

```
$ rpm --verify rpm
$ ls -l /usr/lib/rpm/rpmpopt*
```